# Rewriting with RewriteCond

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got a rewrite rule

```
      RewriteCond    !^ about/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ [NC]
      RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$                        pages/details.php?adid=$1&alias=$2                                          [NC,L]
```

The rule is working fine till i added the cond. Then pages started not loading.

Comment: see https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond / your syntax for your condition seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `RewriteCond` correctly. The condition's first argument is what to match against, like a variable, or a string. The second argument is the condition to place on the first argument. In this case, it looks like you're trying to limit the URI against a regex, so maybe you want something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^about/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ pages/details.php?adid=$1&alias=$2 [NC,L]
```